# Mouse scrolling in MobaXterm tmux

Tags: mouse, tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, scrolling, mobaxterm

On my Linux computer I have the following `.tmux.conf` file:

```
# Enable mouse mode (tmux 2.1 and above)
set -g mouse on
```

This allows me to scroll up and down using the mouse wheel while in a tmux session.

If I use Ubuntu on Windows (WSL) to `ssh` to my Linux computer, this still works fine. I can `tmux attach` to the session and scroll up and down using my mouse just fine. I can also see the entire history of the tmux session (up to the maximum scrollback limit), but I can't see the `ssh` command or the `tmux attach`:
[image]

[image]
Notice I'm able to scroll back all the way to the start of the session, but the `ssh` and `tmux attach` commands don't appear.

However, this fails if I use a MobaXterm WSL-Ubuntu session. I start a WSL-Ubuntu session and use the same commands, but now the scroll wheel just fills in the last command, rather than scrolling up:

[image]

Additionally, if I scroll up using MobaXterm's scrollbar on the right, I can still see the outside history, and not the session history:

[image]

The regular tmux <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd> scrolls through the session history just fine even in MobaXterm though.

How do I get the behaviour from the Linux/WSL terminal in my MobaXterm WSL-Ubuntu session?

Comment: I myself (a lover of MobaXTerm) began using VcXSrv instead for this purpose.  I am not saying that it will fix your problem.. what I am saying is that it has many more options to tweak around problem like this and runs more seamlessly for this application.  Also, I run VcXSrv at startup with the parameters I want and don't need to sweat the 8mb footprint it uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to <del>set the Run method of wsl to 'Native connector' and</del> add

```
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

to `~/.tmux.conf`.

See [Archlinux: Tmux#Scrolling_issues](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Scrolling_issues) for more details.

Comment: I'm not quite clear as to what `smcup` and `rmcup` are, so I don't know if this will cause other issues down the line, but this resolves the problem I had, so I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: @MatedeVita For the existed session, how to make effect ? detach and attach ?

Answer (score 3):

Just press shift while scrolling.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-RjgnoDLio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).